# LIKE function in SQL Server 2008 suggestion needed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table Customer with 2 columns Name and Surname (sql Server 2008). User wants to search by Name-Surname - or just typing Jo Bloggs. Suppose a row is filled with

```
CustomerId        Name    Surname
1                 Jo      Bloggs
```

doing

```
select * from customer where Name like '%Jo%'             will find the records
select * from customer where Surname like '%Bloggs%'      will find the records
```

But How can I make it return records for if user types both Name and Surname eg Jo Bloggs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work whether user enters First Name, Surname or both.

```
SELECT *
FROM customer cus
WHERE ((cus.Name like @FirstName) OR (@FirstName IS NULL)) AND
      ((cus.Surname like @Surname) OR (@Surname IS NULL))
```

I used two variables because entering input values into an SQL string is strongly discouraged, as it exposes to SQL Injection (other than being slower).

Comment: Thanks everybody for your replies.More than one answer would work but I had to choose one.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could also create a computed column and search on that:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.customer
   ADD FullName as Name + ' ' + Surname PERSISTED
```

Now you'd have an extra column `FullName` in your `customer` table, which is always up to date, and you can search for:

```
SELECT (list of fields) FROM dbo.customer 
  WHERE Fullname = 'Jo Bloggs'
```

and since it's a persisted, computed column, you can even put an index on it to make exact searches faster

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from customer where Name like '%Jo%' and Surname like '%Bloggs%'
```

Comment: Should work ... even if the user doesn't type in a name or surname, like '%%' will match all ...

Comment: will work - but it will always do a full table scan, since using `LIKE %Jo%` will not be able to be handled by an index.... performance will be ugly....

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from customer where Name like '%Jo%'             
union
select * from customer where Surname like '%Bloggs%'
```

Comment: This would give `or` I think the OP wants `and`